# Getting results from PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, mysql

With the following, I get "undefined" returned in my alert()

I have the following AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "connect/database.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
        alert(response);
      }
   });
```

And the following PHP:

```
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "the_username";
$password = "the_password";
$dbname = "the_db";

// create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$array_result = array();

$sql = mysqli_query("select * from table where user = 'bobo'");
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array_result[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

print json_encode($array_result)

?>
```

Comment: Can you confirm your SQL query returns any data?

Comment: `print json_encode($array_result)` prints even there are no results. Why?

Comment: You'll want to send "0 results" as json data as well.

Comment: Put the `print` within the `if` after the `while`. It will not print if there's no data.

Comment: @BugHunterUK I have confirmed the SQL returns data. I only get results if the print statement is where it is. Putting it inside the if statement leads to no alert showing.

Comment: The way you have it at the moment, the `print` will execute regardless of whether there's data or not. If it's not working when it's inside the `if` block, it's because the query isn't returning any results.

Answer (score 0):

In response to: "`print json_encode($array_result)` prints even there are no results. Why?"

Put the `print` within the `if` after the `while`. Otherwise the emtpy `$array_result` will be echo'ed.

```
$array_result = array();

$sql = mysqli_query("select * from table where user = 'bobo'");
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array_result[] = $row;
    }

    print json_encode($array_result)
} else {
    echo json_encode(['error' => '0 results found']);
}

$conn->close();
```

You'll want to return json for your error too, as [mkaatman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1207539/mkaatman) suggested

Answer (score 0):

update this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query("select * from table where user = 'bobo'");
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

to this:

```
$sql = "select * from table where user = 'bobo'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Also, Do not echo string, get your error message inside an array and json_encode it:

```
echo json_encode(array(0=>'0 results'));
```

and you can print your result by this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "login.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
    alert(response);
    alert(response[0]);
    alert(response[0]['id']);
  }
});
```

where `id` is one of your query column.

Comment: Also, Do not echo string, get your error message inside an array and json_encode it